# Three.js & OrbitControl.js - Camera into a sphere

Tags: three.js

After a lot of research, I didn't find any information about it. I would like to pilot the camera from the inside of the sphere. The rotating point would be behind the camera in position (0, 0, 0) and look at a variable position (like if you are looking at the star during the night)

A drawing is probably easier to understand than a long explanation:

[image]

In my case, I know how to block the zoom from 0.01 (just to avoid issue if I go to 0) to 0.999 and block the pan. The only issue is about the rotation point. It's always (?) the target is OrbitControl.js. I would like to change it but I don't find any information about how to do that.

This is the piece of code I found in the library :

```
// "target" sets the location of focus, where the control orbits around
// and where it pans with respect to.
this.target = new THREE.Vector3();
// center is old, deprecated; use "target" instead
this.center = this.target;
```

I think in the past, we could apply a center different to the target but now, this variable is useless. If it's impossible with OrbitControl.js, is there another library to do that ?

The idea is to change the rendering of [this project](https://coni63.github.io/v2/index.html).

Many thanks for any clue you may have !

Nicolas

Comment: Is [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_panorama_cube.html) what you want to do? That example does not zoom, though. You'd have to handle zooming by controling `camera.fov` separately.

Comment: I'm more looking at a solution to move the camera in space but with an anchor on the rotation point. I did a quick try now by having the camera fixed on Z axis (for the zoom) and rotate all the space around [link](https://coni63.github.io/v4/index.html). The result is more or less as expected but I feel like a lags during move due to to calculation of the space around the camera compare to my [V2](https://coni63.github.io/v2/index.html) using OrbitControl. In addition, there is bug which creates a "jump" on click I don't know why yet (probably an issue during the calculation of the move).

Comment: Did you find a solution about how to realize this kind of camera inside the sphere?

Comment: Yes, I found a trick. I placed the camera after the center to have a fixed point of rotation and the zoom is still working as expected. This is the code if you want to have a look (https://github.com/Coni63/coni63.github.io/blob/master/includes/js/rendering_spherical_inside.js) and this is the result (https://coni63.github.io/v4/index.html)